# Awaiting coordinates from geocoding google maps API returns pending promise

Tags: node.js, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to return coordinates of given adress with gooogle maps geocoding API and fetch. I am able to log these coordinates inside my get fuction, but I have no idea how to return them from the function to use it somewhere else in the code. Already tried multiple varaitions of two approaches:

```
function getCoordinates1(name) {
  locObj =  fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${name}&key=mykey`).then( (res) => res.json()).then( (data) => 
  { 
    console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location);
    return data.results[0].geometry.location;
  }).then((res) => res);
  }

let coordinates1 = getCoordinates1(latinaze(name2));
console.log(coordinates1);


async function getCoordinates2(name) {
  locObj =  await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${name}&key=mykeyk`).then( (res) => res.json()).then( (data) => 
  { 
    console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location);
    //return data.results[0].geometry.location;
  }).then((res) => res);
  return locObj
  }

let coordinates2 = await getCoordinates2(latinaze(name2));
console.log(coordinates2);
```

First function returns undefined, second returns pending promise. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The first function returns `undefined` because you don't return anything. As simple as that ;)

---

The second function returns a pending promise because you don't wait for the promise to be resolved. The promise gets resolved when the callback inside `then` is invoked, but that happens *after* you return `locObj` in `getCoordinates2`.

---

You should try this:

```
// function definition
async function getCoordinates3(name) {
  const resp = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${name}&key=mykeyk`)
  const data = await resp.json();
  return data.results[0].geometry.location;
}

// usage
const coordinates3 = await getCoordinates3(latinaze(name3));
```

Comment: At first I got an error that await can't be used outside the async function. When i wrapped usage in another async function I am getting Type Error: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

Comment: Can you please inspect the value of `data` when it gets assigned and tell me what it is?

Comment: Actually I rebuilt whole code with different approache and it works now. Thank you for your answers, I really appreciate that ;). I'll answer myself in a while if somebody would have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't return any value from function, so I made it a class method and set a property in function body. Now I can get the value form that property after I call the function:

```
export default class SearchModel {   
  constructor() {
     this.start = ''; 
     this.meta = '';
     this.coors = [];
     this.address = 'none';
   }

   //translate coordinates to address   
   async getAdress(coordinates) {
     try {
       let geocodeCoordinates = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${this.coors[0]},${this.coors[1]}&key=${process.env.API_GM_KEY}`
       const rawData = await fetch(geocodeCoordinates);
       //console.log(await rawData.json());
       return await rawData.json();
     } catch (error) {
       return new Error(`Wild ERROR occured, can't get LocObj. Details: ${error}`);
     }   }

   async displayAdress(coordinates) {
     const data = await this.getAdress(coordinates);
     const dataAdress = await data.results[0].formatted_address;
     this.address = await dataAdress;   }

 }
```